# $f(x,y)=8x^3-9x^2+5xy+3y^2+15$ - Find $\nabla F$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x,y)=8x^3-9x^2+5xy+3y^2+15$

(a) Find
$\nabla F$.

I know I have to differentiate for df/dx and df/dy but I am not sure what to do with the 5xy.

My attempt was:

$\frac{df}{dx}= 24x^2-18x+5y$ and $\frac{df}{dy} = 5x+6y$. I am not sure if this is correct.

(b) Solve $\nabla F =(0,0)$. For part (b) I sub $0$ into both equations to find $x$ and $y$?

Comment: You are on the right track. I think you can finish the solution yourself.

Comment: While taking partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ you should consider $y$ as parameter. Your result $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=24x^2-18x+5y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=5x+6y$ is correct. $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$, then to find at which $x,y$ will $\nabla f=(0,0)$ you need to solve system of equations $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$

Comment: thank you. that makes sense!